# CherryPy passing URL with query params as single parameter in POST

Tags: python, python-3.x, cherrypy

I have a Python 3.4 CherryPy web application with a POST that does some processing on a YouTube URL.

```
POST localhost:8080/api/url=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WS6-vI70oc0
```

If I use a YouTube URL with query params, e.g.:

```
POST localhost:8080/api/url=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WS6-vI70oc0&list=RDGMEM_v2KDBP3d4f8uT-ilrs8fQVMWS6-vI70oc0
```

CherryPy treats this query param (&list) as a query param to my POST API. Output from my API:

```
def POST(self, youtube_url=None, **kwargs):
    print('YOUTUBE URL: %s'%youtube_url)
    print('kwargs: %s'%kwargs)
```

output:

```
YOUTUBE URL: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WS6-vI70oc0
kwargs: {'list': 'RDGMEM_v2KDBP3d4f8uT-ilrs8fQVMWS6-vI70oc0"'}
```

However I would like the entire string to be treated as the youtube_url, without CherryPy automatically separating the ampersand sections into query params.

From the Javascript side I tried encodeURI and surrounding the entire URL with "", which didn't change CherryPy's behavior.

Javascript/HTML side:

```
//input box in HTML:
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="youtubeUrlString" value="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2XNEmxl2rYs" style="height: 34px">

//get input box value in javascript and post
var urlString = document.getElementById('youtubeUrlString').value;
req.open('POST', api_url + '?youtube_url=' + encodeURI(urlString) + '"');
```

Comment: can't you just base64 encode it in the url with [btoa](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/btoa)? And the use [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/base64.html) in python to decode it.

Comment: Are you sure that you are using POST? Can I see the javscript code that it's posting this? You mention that you were using the `encodeURI` function.

Comment: I will edit the question with the Javascript code. @RickyA I will try that, thanks.

Comment: You may also need to uri encode it before sending it. I am not sure if it will produce any non valid characters in the encoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`urlString` variable is as a url component so you should encode it with `encodeURIComponent` instead of `encodeURI`. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3608791/5303401) SO answer answers the difference of them and when to use them.

Comment: Both btoa and encodeURIComponent work, but with btoa I need code on the Python side to handle it so I prefer this solution.